# Bash script for running two commands at specific intervals

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I was playing around with xbacklight program in linux terminal.

What I am trying to do is, set my display to 0% brightness for 20 seconds at every 20 minutes.

Briefly, something like:

```
in every 20 mins:
     xbacklight -set 0%
     continue this way for 20 seconds

     then:
         xbacklight -set 100%
```

How can I set these timeouts properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Power saving technique? `:)`

Comment: @devnull Sounds more like trying to force breaks to reduce eye strain.

Comment: @BroSlow yes brother... you're right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it using cron:

```
*/20 * * * * xbacklight -set 0\% && sleep 20 && xbacklight -set 100\%
```

Note the need to escape the percent signs--they mean something special to cron otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

For permanent use, `cron` is the best solution. For temporary use, there are alternatives.

For example, you could also use `watch` to do this job :

```
watch -n1200 "xbacklight -set 0% && sleep 20 && xbacklight -set 100%"
```

Using bash only :

```
while [ 1 ]; do xbacklight -set 0% && sleep 20 && xbacklight -set 100%; sleep 1200; done
```

Comment: To make the `watch` command work, enclose the entire command to watch in (single) quotes (the rest after `-n1200`) - otherwise, everything after the first `&&` will execute only once, right away.

Comment: Thanks. +1. Allow me a tangent: `while true;` strikes me as both easier to type and clearer in intent (and `true` is POSIX-compliant); is there an advantage to `while [ 1 ];`?

Comment: This is one of my writing habits. This is not necessarily a good habit.

Comment: Thanks - I was genuinely curious and wasn't sure if I was missing something.